# Change default folder where claws-mail stores mails

Tags: linux, claws-mail

How can I change the directory where `claws-mail` stores the mail folders? By default it stores it in `/home/USERNAME/`.

I would like to have them in a hidden directory. Searching the web did not yield any usable result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried another research and lucky me, I found the solution: Just name your **mailbox name** as a path relative from `/home/` OR as an absolute path:

[image]

For example one could enter: `.my_mailboxes/main_mailbox`

I found that simple solution here: http://lists.claws-mail.org/pipermail/users/2012-February/001496.html

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I change the directory where claws-mail stores the mail folders?

Look in `$HOME/.claws-mail/clawsrc` and change the value of `mailbox`.

> The default location for Claws Mail's configuration files is
>   `$HOME/.claws-mail/`. (The command `claws-mail --config-dir` shows the
>   location.)
>
> They are in plain text format and quite easy to understand, so don't
>   fear to take a look into them using a text editor.
>
> `clawsrc`
>
> main configuration: nearly all options from the settings window, e.g.
>   **mailbox location**, font entries, etc.

Source [What configuration files are there, and what are they used for?](http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Installation_and_Configuration#What_configuration_files_are_there.2C_and_what_are_they_used_for.3F)

Comment: I looked for every entry in `clawsrc` and could not find anything helpful. But I stumbled upon a solution which should work in general from within the gui.

Comment: @stackunderflow Hmm. Now you have a fix I'm curious if you can find the value `.my_mailboxes/main_mailbox` somewhere in one of the claws configuration files Note there are many in `$HOME/.claws-mail/`:)

Comment: It is stored in `accountrc[.bak|.tmpl]` and `folderlist.xml`